# C# problems with FileInfo List(add Image)

Tags: c#

How can I insert `Image` object into `FileInfo` list?

I have a list with images of this type

```
public  List<FileInfo> _imagesList = new List<FileInfo>();
```

But I need to add image to this list using a method like this one:

```
public void AddImage(Image img)
{

}
```

I tried using this method

```
 public void AddImage(string pathToImage)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathToImage);
                 _imagesList.Add(file);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось загрузить изображение. Ошибка : " + e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<Image>` ?

Comment: What do you need? A list of files or a list of images?

Comment: The FileInfo class provides properties and methods for working with files. The Image class, on the other hand, provides methods and properties for working with images (which might not even exist on disk). What exactly are you trying to do so we can point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain why **you can't do that**. `Image` class does not have any references to file which was used to create that image. When you create `Image` instance with

```
Image.FromFile(filename)
```

File name is not stored anywhere. All you will have inside `Image` instance is an array of bytes which is initialized this way:

```
Stream dataStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
image.rawData = new byte[(int) dataStream.Length];
dataStream.Read(image.rawData, 0, (int) dataStream.Length);
```

So, the point is - you can't get file name from which `Image` was created. Actually image can be create not from file - from any stream (network stream, memory stream). `Image` is not related to any file, thus you can't insert it to list of `FileInfo` objects.

Well, as a workaround, you can save `Image` to file. And then insert that file to list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this, [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx) accept one arguments in its constructor: `fileName`.

You should have something like this:

```
public  List<FileInfo> _imagesList = new List<FileInfo>();

public void Main()
{
   AddImage("YourImagePath1");
   AddImage("YourImagePath2");
   // ...
}

public void AddImage(string path)
{
   _imagesList.Add(new FileInfo(path));
   //var img = Image.FromFile(path); // do this if you need to load your image
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You changed your question and your code now looks like mine, what was the issue in the code you used to have?

Comment: Where is this Path property you speak of (not saying it doesn't exist, but I don't see it)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image_properties.aspx

Comment: There is not because we don't know what is the namespace of this class, but if he saves the image somewhere he should be able to return a path (if `Image` is a custom class or as an extension method).

Comment: I have something like this Image img = Image.FromFile(@"D:\1.jpg");   And now i need to add this img to my _ImageList that have FileInfo type

Comment: How i can see it is imposible

Comment: Look at my updated code, please clarify if it doesn't answer to your question.

Comment: No? it dosen`t answer to  my question) I have Image obj, i dont know his path/

Comment: You said `D:\1.jpg`. How can you load an image if you don't know the path?

Answer (score 0):

you can either use the method you gave, adding `new FileInfo(pathToImage)` or change your list so it'll contain `Image` items

you can use

```
public  List<Image> _imagesList = new List<Image>();
```

for example. if you share more information i could help you more. this looks like an XY problem so maybe you should tell us what's the real problem

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i need to use only public  List<FileInfo> _imagesList = new List<FileInfo>();

Comment: If it possible to add Image obj to FileInfo List??

Comment: @Udjen images do not inherit FileInfo, so you'll have to use their path... is that ok?

Comment: How can i reciev image path? I have my image obj like this Image img = Image.FromFile(@"D:\1.jpg")

Comment: _imageList.Add(img.path)??  But how?

Comment: @Udjen have you opened the image from some location?

Comment: I wrote class, and using my method after, programmer can add Image obj into. So i dont know path of image)

Comment: @Udjen well, either you make the programmers give you the image path, or you have to find a workaround this problem. tell me why is it have to be a list of FileInfo?

Comment: I decided to rewrite my code and make public  List<Image> _imagesList = new List<Image>();

Comment: @Udjen, no problem... hmm... if you can please accept my answer, i mean, if that's the solution you found the most correct...